# Applications / services which allow you to run a virtual class over the Internet?

Tags: voip

I'm asking for a software with a modern UI to give me, as a teacher, ability to communicate with my students, especially on their mobile phones/tablets with enough features to manage a virtual class.

[image]

Required features:

- Nice design
- Instance Communication
- Running in web browsers (APPs for special env such as Android/Linux will be great)
- Video telephony, file sharing (for documents)
- Picture in picture
- Group chat (where you also could share links, if there's no direct file-sharing) | My thanks for @Izzy because of suggestions for adding details in comments
- I'm not experienced and don't have any more idea on requierments!

Comment: I'm a teacher. I want to have online courses. Features? I'm not sure. I was thinking about basics! I don't have any idea on what I will need!

Comment: Thanks for the update, mini! Looks much clearer now. If I get that right, you need some kind of "video telephony". Let me give you some triggers: file sharing (for documents), or a "group chat" (where you also could share links, if there's no direct file-sharing)? "Running in web-browser" of course makes it available for all systems. Nice-to-haves surely include native tools for other platforms besides Android/Linux (e.g. iOS/Windows – as much as mentioning Android/Linux alone raised a warm smile on my end, as those are my prefered platforms)?